# replace NA values of two data frames with matching ID and dates in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with different lengths in rows and columns

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2010", "01/01/2020"),
           Germany = c(5, 8, 9),
            France = c(4, NA, 7),
        Luxembourg = c(10, 6, 3)
) -> df1
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("01/01/1990", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2010", "01/01/2020"),
           Germany = c(1, 9, 7, NA),
            France = c(10, 3, 9, 6),
        Luxembourg = c(10, NA, NA, 7),
           Belgium = c(NA, 8, 1, 9)
) -> df2
```

[image: dfs]

I have to create a third df **(df3)** where,

1. NA values of **df1** are replaced with the values of **df2** by matching **IDs** and **Dates** and viceversa (the NA from df2 replaced by df1)
2. The values of df1 are priority (=TRUE)
3. All those columns that are not in one data frame (like Belgium in this case) should also be included in the df3

**df3** should look like this:

[image: results]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

We can do a join `on` the 'Date' and use `fcoalesce` to replace the NA with the corresponding non-NA

```
library(data.table)
nm2 <- intersect(names(df2)[-1], names(df1)[-1])
df3 <- copy(df2)
setDT(df3)[df1, (nm2) := Map(fcoalesce, mget(nm2),
       mget(paste0('i.', nm2))), on = .(Date)]
```

-output

```
df3
#         Date Germany France Luxembourg Belgium
#1: 01/01/1990       1     10         10      NA
#2: 01/01/2000       9      3         10       8
#3: 01/01/2010       7      9          6       1
#4: 01/01/2020       9      6          7       9
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = 'Date') %>% 
   mutate(Date, across(ends_with(".x"), 
    ~ coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), "\\.x$", ".y"))))) %>% 
   select(-ends_with('.y')) %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_remove(., "\\.x$"), ends_with('.x'))
```

Comment: Dear akrun is there a way of achieving the same result with tidyverse. I think `left_join` would be useful but there remains some NA values to be replaced by values of df1.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes, you can use `coalesce` in `dplyr` i.e. `left_join(df3, df1, by = 'Date')` and then you may need to grab the `.x` and `.y` columns as thse columns get suffixed when there are duplicates

Comment: Thank you very much. OK let me try that.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it is a little tricky because it creates those columns and there are some columns in df2 that doesn't have a match on df1

Comment: I guess you are right because we need to consider matching rows as well. I've never done that before and don't know how to do it.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR you can do `left_join(df2, df1, by = 'Date') %>% mutate(Date, across(ends_with(".x"), ~ coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), "\\.x", ".y"))))) %>% select(-ends_with('.y')) %>% rename_with(~ str_remove(., "\\.x$"), ends_with('.x'))`

Comment: `setDT(df3)[df1, (nm2) := Map(fcoalesce, mget(nm2), mget(paste0('i.', nm2))), on = .(Date)]` in this step I get the following:   logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.

Comment: @Drop With `setDT(df3)` it is convertted to data.table.  So the error part is nnot clear.  I checked couple of times and I am not getting error.  May be it is related to version of data.table.  Can you also do `setDT(df1)` before the step

Comment: Thank you very much that was a great solution! I only have one question: Why do we need to escape `.x` in the `str_replace` used in `coalesce`?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR The reason is that I am only looping over the `.x` columns`, then get the column names with `cur_column()`, replace the suffix part with `.y` to `get` the column values and then with `coalesce` do the replacement from that corresponding column

Comment: I got it, it may mistakenly find `'L.yembourg.x'` as well. Thank you very much for teaching us these great solutions.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR The `.` matches any character.  So we need to escape it with `\\.`. Also, it may be better to use `\\.x$` to specify at the end of the string

Comment: I think we did not escape `.` in `.y` cause the replacement argument cannot be interpreted as `regex`. Am I right?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it is the replacement part where it is evaluated literally.  If we want to evaluate the pattern part literally then have to specify `fixed(".x")`

Comment: I totally understand. Thank you very much. It was an amazing solution by you. I almost know nothing about package `data.table`. Do you think there are considerable things that can be done by it and not by tidyverse packages?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I think tidyverse made it easier for faster prototype/code development/debugging etc.  But, if your data is really big, then from my experience data.table may be more efficient as it does assignment by reference, also with set functions, it would be fast.

Comment: I understand. I just have to learn it sooner than later.Dear @akrun I can't thank you enough for your time and generosity.

Comment: There's a new `dplyr` function called `rows_update` for this. I think it's as simple as `rows_update(df1, df2, by = "Date")`. Experimental lifecycle phase, for now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `data.table` option

```
cols <- setdiff(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), "Date")
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2),
  on = "Date"
][
  ,
  c(cols) :=
    Map(
      fcoalesce,
      .SD[, cols, with = FALSE],
      .SD[, paste0("i.", cols), with = FALSE]
    )
][,
  .SD,
  .SDcols = patterns("^[^i]")
]
```

giving

```
         Date Germany France Luxembourg Belgium
1: 01/01/1990       1     10         10      NA
2: 01/01/2000       5      4         10       8
3: 01/01/2010       8      9          6       1
4: 01/01/2020       9      7          3       9
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `dplyr` only using `mutate(across..`.

I also propose use of `full_join` instead of `left_join` or `right_join` as `full_join` will take all rows from `df1` or `df2` as opposed to left or right joins.

```r
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2010", "01/01/2020"),
  Germany = c(5, 8, 9),
  France = c(4, NA, 7),
  Luxembourg = c(10, 6, 3)
) -> df1
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("01/01/1990", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2010", "01/01/2020"),
  Germany = c(1, 9, 7, NA),
  France = c(10, 3, 9, 6),
  Luxembourg = c(10, NA, NA, 7),
  Belgium = c(NA, 8, 1, 9)
) -> df2

library(dplyr)


df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = 'Date', suffix = c('_x', '_y')) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_x'), ~coalesce(., get(sub('_x', '_y', cur_column()))),
                .names = '{sub("_x", "", {.col})}')) %>%
  select(!ends_with('_x') & !ends_with('_y'))

#>         Date Belgium Germany France Luxembourg
#> 1 01/01/2000       8       5      4         10
#> 2 01/01/2010       1       8      9          6
#> 3 01/01/2020       9       9      7          3
#> 4 01/01/1990      NA       1     10         10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Store as a variable a list denoting each data.frame's column names: 
# cnames => character vector
cnames <- list(names(df1), names(df2))

# Determine which vector of names is required in the resulting data.frame 
# required_vecs => character vector
required_vecs <- cnames[[which.max(lengths(cnames))]]

# Merge the data: full_data => data.frame
full_data <- merge(
  df1,
  df2,
  by = "Date",
  all = TRUE
)

# Resolve the vector names of vectors requiring coalescing: 
# clsce_required_vecs=> character vector
clsce_required_vecs <- setdiff(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), c("Date"))

# Resolve the vector names of vectors not requiring coalescing: 
# nt_rqrd_vecs => character vector
nt_rqrd_vecs <- setdiff(unlist(cnames), clsce_required_vecs)

# Split-Apply-Combine data requiring coalescing: coalesced_data => data.frame
coalesced_data <- setNames(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      cbind, 
      lapply(
        clsce_required_vecs, 
        function(x) {
          # Subset the data to only contain relevant vectors: sbst => data.frame
          sbst <- full_data[,grepl(x, names(full_data))]
          # Split each column (of the same data) into a data.frame in a list:
          # same_vecs => list of data.frames
          same_vecs <- split.default(sbst, seq_len(ncol(sbst)))
          # Rename the data.frames as required and row-bind them into a single df:
          # vector => GlobalEnv()
          Reduce(
            function(y, z){
              replace(y, is.na(y), z[is.na(y)])
            }, 
            do.call(cbind, same_vecs)
          )
        }
      )
    ), row.names = NULL), 
clsce_required_vecs)
    
# Column bind and order the columns:
res <- cbind(full_data[, nt_rqrd_vecs], coalesced_data)[,required_vecs]
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Date, ~Germany, ~France, ~Luxembourg,
  "01/01/2000",        5,       4,          10,
  "01/01/2010",        8,      NA,           6,
  "01/01/2020",        9,       7,           3
)
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Date, ~Germany, ~France, ~Luxembourg, ~Belgium,
  "01/01/1990",        1,      10,          10,       NA,
  "01/01/2000",        9,       3,          NA,        8,
  "01/01/2010",        7,       9,          NA,        1,
  "01/01/2020",       NA,       6,           7,        9
)

bind_rows(df1 %>%
            mutate(priority = 1),
          df2 %>%
            mutate(priority = 2)) %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  arrange(priority) %>%
  summarise(across(-priority, ~ first(na.omit(.))))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   Date       Germany France Luxembourg Belgium
#>   <date>       <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 1990-01-01       1     10         10      NA
#> 2 2000-01-01       5      4         10       8
#> 3 2010-01-01       8      9          6       1
#> 4 2020-01-01       9      7          3       9
```